# What is Hindley-Milner?

Tags: functional-programming, types, inference, hindley-milner

I encountered this term *Hindley-Milner*, and I'm not sure if grasp what it means.

I've read the following posts:

- Steve Yegge - [Dynamic Languages Strike Back](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/05/dynamic-languages-strike-back.html)
- Steve Yegge - [The Pinocchio Problem](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/01/pinocchio-problem.html)
- Daniel Spiewak - [What is Hindley-Milner? (and why is it cool?)](https://web.archive.org/web/20181118000004/http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/what-is-hindley-milner-and-why-is-it-cool)

But there is no single entry for this term in wikipedia where usually offers me a concise explanation.
<sup>**Note** - one has [now been added](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner)</sup>

What is it?
What languages and tools implement or use it?
Would you please offer a concise answer?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Hindley-Milner is a **type system** discovered independently by Roger Hindley (who was looking at logic) and later by Robin Milner (who was looking at programming languages).  The advantages of Hindley-Milner are

- It supports **polymorphic** functions; for example, a function that can give you the length of the list independent of the type of the elements, or a function does a binary-tree lookup independent of the type of keys stored in the tree.
- Sometimes a function or value can have **more than one type**, as in the example of the length function: it can be "list of integers to integer", "list of strings to integer", "list of pairs to integer", and so on.  In this case, a signal advantage of the Hindley-Milner system is that **each well-typed term has a unique "best" type**, which is called the *principal type*.  The principal type of the list-length function is "for any `a`, function from list of `a` to integer".  Here `a` is a so-called "type parameter," which is **explicit in lambda calculus** but **implicit in most programming languages**.  The use of type parameters explains why Hindley-Milner is a system that implements ***parametric* polymorphism**.  (If you write a definition of the length function in ML, you can see the type parameter thus:

  ```
   fun 'a length []      = 0
     | 'a length (x::xs) = 1 + length xs
  ```
- *If* a term has a Hindley-Milner type, then **the principal type can be inferred without requiring any type declarations** or other annotations by the programmer.  (This is a mixed blessing, as anyone can attest who has ever been handled a large chunk of ML code with no annotations.)

Hindley-Milner is the basis for the type system of almost every statically typed functional language.  Such languages in common use include

- The ML family ([Standard ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) and [Objective Caml](http://caml.inria.fr/))
- [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org)
- [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl/)

All these languages have extended Hindley-Milner; Haskell, Clean, and Objective Caml do so in ambitious and unusual ways.  (Extensions are required to deal with mutable variables, since basic Hindley-Milner can be subverted using, for example, a mutable cell holding a list of values of unspecified type.  Such problems are dealt with by an extension called the [*value restriction*](http://users.cs.fiu.edu/~smithg/cop4555/valrestr.html).)

Many other minor languages and tools based on typed functional languages use Hindley-Milner.

Hindley-Milner is a restriction of [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), which allows more types but which **requires annotations by the programmer**.

Comment: @NormanRamsey I know this is wicked old but thanks for clearing up what has annoyed me endlessly: Everytime I refer to hindley-milner type system someone chimes in talking about type inference to the point that I've begun to question whether HM is a type system or just the inference algorithm... Thankyou is in order I guess to wikipedia for misinforming people about this to the point that they even confused me..

Comment: Why is it *parametrically* polymorphic, as opposed to simply polymorphic? The example with Any you gave, I see it as an example if polymorphism - where subtypes can be used instead of the supertype which is specified in the definition, and not parametric polymorphism ala C++ where the actual type is specified by the programmer to create a new function.

Comment: @jcora: A few years late, but for the benefit of future readers: it’s called *parametric* polymorphism due to the property of [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity), which means for any type you plug in, all instances of a function like `length :: forall a. [a] -> Int` must behave the same regardless of `a`—it’s opaque; you know nothing about it. There’s no `instanceof` (Java generics) nor “duck typing” (C++ templates) unless you add extra type constraints (Haskell typeclasses). With parametricity you can get some nice proofs about precisely what a function can/can’t do.

Comment: "as anyone can attest who has ever been handled a large chunk of ML code with no annotations.". Oh yes.

Answer (score 14):

You may be able to find the original papers using Google Scholar or CiteSeer -- or your local university library.  The first is old enough that you may have to find bound copies of the journal, I couldn't find it online.  The link that I found for the other one was broken, but there might be others.  You'll certainly be able to find papers that cite these.

Hindley, Roger J, *The principal type scheme of an object in combinatory logic*, 
Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 1969.

Milner, Robin, *A Theory of Type Polymorphism*, Journal of Computer and System Sciences, 1978.

Comment: The latter one can be found here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.67.5276

Comment: The former: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-146-00/S0002-9947-1969-0253905-6/S0002-9947-1969-0253905-6.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Simple Hindley-Milner type inference implementation in C# :

[Hindley-Milner type inference over (Lisp-ish) S-expressions, in under 650 lines of C#](https://repl.it/CmiB/7)

Note the implementation is in the range of only 270 or so lines of C# (for the algorithm W proper and the few data structures to support it, anyway).

Usage excerpt:

```
    // ...

    var syntax =
        new SExpressionSyntax().
        Include
        (
            // Not-quite-Lisp-indeed; just tolen from our host, C#, as-is
            SExpressionSyntax.Token("\\/\\/.*", SExpressionSyntax.Commenting),
            SExpressionSyntax.Token("false", (token, match) => false),
            SExpressionSyntax.Token("true", (token, match) => true),
            SExpressionSyntax.Token("null", (token, match) => null),

            // Integers (unsigned)
            SExpressionSyntax.Token("[0-9]+", (token, match) => int.Parse(match)),

            // String literals
            SExpressionSyntax.Token("\\\"(\\\\\\n|\\\\t|\\\\n|\\\\r|\\\\\\\"|[^\\\"])*\\\"", (token, match) => match.Substring(1, match.Length - 2)),

            // For identifiers...
            SExpressionSyntax.Token("[\\$_A-Za-z][\\$_0-9A-Za-z\\-]*", SExpressionSyntax.NewSymbol),

            // ... and such
            SExpressionSyntax.Token("[\\!\\&\\|\\<\\=\\>\\+\\-\\*\\/\\%\\:]+", SExpressionSyntax.NewSymbol)
        );

    var system = TypeSystem.Default;
    var env = new Dictionary<string, IType>();

    // Classic
    var @bool = system.NewType(typeof(bool).Name);
    var @int = system.NewType(typeof(int).Name);
    var @string = system.NewType(typeof(string).Name);

    // Generic list of some `item' type : List<item>
    var ItemType = system.NewGeneric();
    var ListType = system.NewType("List", new[] { ItemType });

    // Populate the top level typing environment (aka, the language's "builtins")
    env[@bool.Id] = @bool;
    env[@int.Id] = @int;
    env[@string.Id] = @string;
    env[ListType.Id] = env["nil"] = ListType;

    //...

    Action<object> analyze =
        (ast) =>
        {
            var nodes = (Node[])visitSExpr(ast);
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", node.Id, system.Infer(env, node));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("... Done.");
        };

    // Parse some S-expr (in string representation)
    var source =
        syntax.
        Parse
        (@"
            (
                let
                (
                    // Type inference ""playground""

                    // Classic..                        
                    ( id ( ( x ) => x ) ) // identity

                    ( o ( ( f g ) => ( ( x ) => ( f ( g x ) ) ) ) ) // composition

                    ( factorial ( ( n ) => ( if ( > n 0 ) ( * n ( factorial ( - n 1 ) ) ) 1 ) ) )

                    // More interesting..
                    ( fmap (
                        ( f l ) =>
                        ( if ( empty l )
                            ( : ( f ( head l ) ) ( fmap f ( tail l ) ) )
                            nil
                        )
                    ) )

                    // your own...
                )
                ( )
            )
        ");

    // Visit the parsed S-expr, turn it into a more friendly AST for H-M
    // (see Node, et al, above) and infer some types from the latter
    analyze(source);

    // ...
```

... which yields:

```
id : Function<`u, `u>

o : Function<Function<`z, `aa>, Function<`y, `z>, Function<`y, `aa>>

factorial : Function<Int32, Int32>

fmap : Function<Function<`au, `ax>, List<`au>, List<`ax>>

... Done.
```

See also [Brian McKenna's JavaScript implementation](https://bitbucket.org/puffnfresh/js-type-inference/src) on bitbucket, which also helps to get started (worked for me).

'HTH,