# scala overloaded method value cannot be applied

Tags: scala

The following code works:

```
def bbb(v: Double => Unit)(a: Double): Unit = v(a)
bbb{v: Double => v == 0 }(5)
bbb{v: Double =>  Array(v) }(5)
```

But if I overload `bbb` as follows, it doesn't work unless I manually assign the type signature for the first `bbb` call:

```
def bbb(v: Double => Unit)(a: Double): Unit = v(a)
def bbb(v: Double => Array[Double])(a: Double): Array[Double] = v(a)
bbb{v: Double => v == 0 }(5) // bbb{(v => v == 0):(Double => Unit)}(5)
bbb{v: Double =>  Array(v) }(5)
```

Comment: Check this one explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899320/when-does-scala-need-parameter-types-for-anonymous-and-expanded-functions

Comment: @ipoteka I think the two questions are different? `v: Double => v == 0` can not apply to `def bbb(v: Double => Array[Double])` but it can apply to `def bbb(v: Double => Unit)`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is related to implicit conversions. In the first case, when you only have a definition that results in a Unit, even though you get results such as Boolean or Array, an implicit conversion to Unit is triggered returning you always the expected Unit.

When you overload, this implicit conversion is no longer applied, but the overloading resolution mechanism instead. You can find how this works in more detail in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution)

Comment: I originally think it's related with covariance. It is pretty late now, I will look at the stuff you provide tomorrow.

Comment: In particular, args are typed without an expected type, so the function literal is `Double => Boolean` instead of `Double => Unit`; if it expects `Double => Unit`, "value discarding" is what allows it and `-Ywarn-value-discard` warns about it, since it is often undesirable.

Comment: Thank you both, both are right. `Unit` is at the same level as `Boolean` in the type hierarchy. It is implicit conversion, specifically `value discarding`, not subtyping.