# More on generic Scala functions

Tags: scala, haskell, polymorphism, numeric

Trying to implement, in Scala, the following Haskell function (from Learn You a Haskell...) so that it works with Int, Double, etc.

```
doubleUs x y = x * 2 + y * 2
```

Note that this is similar to [Scala: How to define "generic" function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252915/scala-how-to-define-generic-function-parameters)

Here's my attempt and error. Can someone explain what's happening and offer a solution. Thanks.

```
scala> def doubleUs[A](x:A,y:A)(implicit numeric: Numeric[A]): A = numeric.plus(numeric.times(x,2),numeric.times(y,2)) 
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: A
       def doubleUs[A](x:A,y:A)(implicit numeric: Numeric[A]): A = numeric.plus(numeric.times(x,2),numeric.times(y,2))
```

Comment: Oah... generic math looks so complicated in scala...

Comment: @FUZxxl Consequence of Java legacy and interoperability.

Comment: Coming from a C#/F#/Haskell/Mathematica background, I have to say my heart beats with bliss upon such sights of ugliness that plague languages I deliberately chose to keep away from after brief initial exposure, such as Java/Scala ^_^! There is no god in heavens that would not pity the ones that suffer such mess on a daily basis.

Comment: @Cetin: In Scala, generic math is ugly. But it *can* do generic math. C#, F# *cannot* even do generic math in a typesafe manner. Mathematica being a dynamically typed language, the comparison doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using the `Int` literal `2` but scala is expecting the `Numeric` type `A`.
The [Scala Numeric API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) has a utility function- `def fromInt(x:Int): T`. This is what you want to use, so replace your usage of `2` with `numeric.fromInt(2)`

```
def doubleUs[A](x:A,y:A)(implicit numeric: Numeric[A]): A =
  numeric.plus (numeric.times (x, numeric.fromInt (2)), numeric.times (y, numeric.fromInt (2)))
```

Also, since a Numeric instance defines an implicit conversion to an Ops, you can `import numeric._` and then say `x * fromInt(2) + y * fromInt(2)`.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to what @Dylan said, you can make it look a little less tedious by importing into scope the contents of `Numeric` implicit as shown below:

```
scala> def doubleUs[N](x: N, y: N)(implicit ev: Numeric[N]) = {
     |   import ev._
     |   x * fromInt(2) + y * fromInt(2)
     | }
doubleUs: [N](x: N, y: N)(implicit ev: Numeric[N])N

scala> doubleUs(3, 4)
res9: Int = 14

scala> doubleUs(8.9, 1.2)
res10: Double = 20.2
```

Answer (score 11):

You need some implicits in scope:

```
def doubleUs[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]) = {
  import num._
  implicit def fromInt(i: Int) = num.fromInt(i)
  x * 2 + y * 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dylan essentially answered, but for what it's worth, let me suggest to use the context bound syntax instead of the implicit argument (both are equivalent, and the former is automatically rewritten into the latter by the compiler).

```
def doubleUs[A : Numeric](x : A, y : A) : A = {
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
  import num.{plus,times,fromInt}
  plus(times(x, fromInt(2)), times(y, fromInt(2)))
}
```

Comment: It's called a context bound, not a type annotation syntax.