# Defining a trait with a method that return a value of different numeric type

Tags: scala, numeric, traits

I have several classes that contains a numeric value (that value can be bounded, can be only positive, aso...)

I must make some basic operations (like summing) based on a 'supertype' of those classes. So I defined a trait for it thinking it's gonna be trivial...

Here is a runnable excerpt of my code :

```
object Main extends App {

  trait WithValue[A] {
    def value: A
  }

  class BoundedNumber[A](val lower: A, val upper: A, val value: A) extends WithValue[A]

  case class NumberBetween0and99(value: Int) extends BoundedNumber[Int](0, 99, value)
  case class UnboundedPositiveInt(value: Int) extends WithValue[Int]
  case class UnboundedPositiveDouble(value: Double) extends WithValue[Double]


  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val map: Map[Symbol, WithValue[_]] = Map(
      'foo -> UnboundedPositiveDouble(5),
      'bar -> UnboundedPositiveInt(10),
      'baz -> NumberBetween0and99(55)
    )
    for (m <- map) println(5 + m._2.value)
  }
}
```

The for loop fail :

```
overloaded method value + with alternatives: (...) cannot be applied to (Any)
```

I am running in circle with this really trivial problem for some hours... guess my fluency in Scala is far from 'fluent'...

Comment: I think you need to use the numeric typeclass pattern (give an implicit numeric object to a + function) or make WithValue covariant in A, e.g. WithValue[+A] and then use a basic numeric type in your map type annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your problem by using a similar method as this: [Scala: How to define "generic" function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252915/scala-how-to-define-generic-function-parameters)