# How should I write general function take two variable and add them in scala?

Tags: scala

I tried this way:

```
  def add[A](a:A, b:A): A = {
    a + b
  }
```

The compiler says:

> Error:(47, 9) type mismatch;  found   : A  required: String
>       a + b

Any one tell me why this error happened? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: How to define "generic" function parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252915/scala-how-to-define-generic-function-parameters)

Answer (score 8):

Actually Scala doesn't see any common grounds between a Double's + and a an Int's + and also scala keeps this restriction by using Numeric. and its subclasses like Fractional and Integral. You can do your work in different ways like below

```
def addition[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = {
  import num._
  x + y
}
```

or

```
def add[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit numeric: Numeric[A]): A = numeric.plus(x, y)
```

Comment: Or `def add[A:Numeric](x: A, y: A): A = implicitly[Numeric[A]].plus(x,y)`, another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are getting the error because the `compiler` cannot `infer the actual type of variable a and b` and therefore, it `cannot determine` if the `+` method is defined for that `type A`.

Since you want to add `two variables` and not just two numbers,you could pass `anonymous function` in the method to define how you want to `perform the addition` between those variables. In this way, you could specify, how you want to add `two strings` or `two integers` or two parameters of any type:

```
def add[A](a:A,b:A,sum:(A,A)=> A): A = {
    sum(a,b)
  }

add("john","watson", (a:String,b:String) => a.concat(" "+b))
//result: john watson

add(1,2,(a:Int,b:Int) => a + b)
//result: 3
```

Comment: That's a pretty poor solution. Defining a "generic" add where you have to pass the specific add every time you use it isn't very useful

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, is there any  "perfect" solution here? if you have no information about the `A` here, how can you define its `add` action?

Comment: "the compiler cannot infer the type of variable A" There is no variable `A` in this code. There is a _type parameter_ `A`, but it doesn't need to be inferred here.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yes, right, actually i meant `type of variable a and b`.I have edited my answer.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I am quite aware of that. I expect you wanted to direct this comment elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, Oops. Apologies. Wrong person indeed. Removed/readded the comment

Comment: @armnotstrong you can either use Numeric - thereby providing "information about the A" , as in the previous answer, or a typeclass (implicit definition of addition). It you have "no information about A" you cannot know addition is even possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use type classes to achieve this.

First, define a base trait for your operation

```
trait Addable[T] {
  def +(x: T, y: T): T
}
```

Next, define an default implicits for all the types you wish to be able to add:

```
implicit object LongAddable extends Addable[Long] {
  def +(x:Long, y:Long) = x + y
}
implicit object IntAddable extends Addable[Int] {
  def +(x:Int, y:Int) = x + y
}
implicit object StringAddable extends Addable[String] {
  def +(x:String, y:String) = s"${x}${y}"
}
```

Finally, define your method in terms of your type class, using implicit evidence to constrain your parameters:

```
def add[A](a:A, b:A)(implicit ev: Addable[A]): A = {
     ev.+(a,b)
}
```

Putting all that together allows you to add Ints,Longs, and Strings, all with the same method.

```
scala> object Example {
     |   trait Addable[T] {
     |     def +(x: T, y: T): T
     |   }
     |   implicit object LongAddable extends Addable[Long] {
     |     def +(x:Long, y:Long) = x + y
     |   }
     |   implicit object IntAddable extends Addable[Int] {
     |     def +(x:Int, y:Int) = x + y
     |   }
     |   implicit object StringAddable extends Addable[String] {
     |     def +(x:String, y:String) = s"${x}${y}"
     |   }
     |   def add[A](a:A, b:A)(implicit ev: Addable[A]): A = {
     |       ev.+(a,b)
     |   }
     | }
defined object Example

scala> Example.add(1,2)
res2: Int = 3

scala> Example.add(1L,2)
res3: Long = 3

scala> Example.add("2", "3")
res4: String = 23
```