# Type inference implemented in C++

Tags: c++, type-inference, hindley-milner

Is there an implementation in C++, of [Damas-Hindley-Milner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399312/what-is-hindley-milner) style type inference, preferably using modern C++ techniques?

Comment: Erm... what is Damas-Hindley-Milner style type inference? Any links would be nice. Also note that C++11 adds `auto` for type inference, and `template`s are by-nature inferencing types when used as function parameters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "Damas-Hindley-Milner style type inference" is? I don't feel like googling it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I imagine that this is a situation where if you have to look it up you probably won't have the answer, either...

Comment: I think the question isn't `{implementation of {type inference in C++}}`, but rather, `{implementation in C++ of {type inference}}`. @Keveman: Check the other questions on SO (I added the right tag), maybe they're of some help... maybe the source code of a C++ compiler can be educational, since templates are sort of a functional programming language.

Comment: Changed the description as per Kerrek's suggestion.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, but templates aren't even "type checked" prior to their instantiation, so I'd doubt an implementation of C++ templates would contain very much that's similar to HM type inference. Plus: I'd imagine that any C++ compiler's source code would be particular easy to read/understand.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399312/what-is-hindley-milner

Answer (score 14):

Here's [my implementation of Hindley-Milner type inference in C++11](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/hindley_milner), based on the [Python code by Robert Smallshire](http://www.smallshire.org.uk/sufficientlysmall/2010/04/11/a-hindley-milner-type-inference-implementation-in-python/), the [Scala code by Andrew Forrest](http://dysphoria.net/2009/06/28/hindley-milner-type-inference-in-scala/), the Perl code by Nikita Borisov and the [paper "Basic Polymorphic Typechecking" by Cardelli](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/BasicTypechecking.pdf).

It makes heavy use of `boost::variant` and `boost::apply_visitor`.

Comment: You may also find `boost::disjoint_sets` useful for union-find operations.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you won't have much luck; the functional guys who write this stuff generally don't do it in C++! Most of the compilers you could go to are used to compile themselves (eg for OCaml, or GHC).

So, if someone did do Hindley-Milner as a toy project, it's probably not on the net; if it was part of compiler, then it's unlikely to be in C++.

Possible things that come to mind:

- [Hugs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hugs) for Haskell is in C; there'll be some C sources in there somewhere that do what you want, and Haskell's a nice familiar sugar. Not the C++ you want though.
- I don't know anything about F#, but I think that's HM, and if anyone has written a fat functional compiler in C++ with modern techniques, it could be probably MS. Obviously closed source though.

Answer (score 1):

We have a type inference engine here (https://github.com/ltcmelo/psychec). Our approach is implemented after the HM(X) algorithm by Pottier and Remy, with separate stages for constraint generation and type inference properly. Constraint generation is implemented in C++, but type resolution is implemented in Haskell (sorry!). The algorithm infers types for C programs, to reconstruct code partially available. The tool is available on-line: http://cuda.dcc.ufmg.br/psyche-c/. You enter part of a C program, and it produces type declarations that are sufficient for compiling it.

Regards,

Fernando