# Example of type in System F that is not available in Hindley Milner type inference

Tags: types, type-inference, inference, hindley-milner, system-f

Under ['What is Hindley Milner'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399312/what-is-hindley-milner) it states:

> Hindley-Milner is a restriction of [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), which allows more types but which requires annotations by the programmer.

My question is, **What is an example of a type available in System F, that is not available in Hindley Milner (type inference)?**

(The assumption being that the inference of System F types has been proven undecideable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hindley/Milner does not support higher-rank polymorphic types, i.e., types where the universal quantifier is nested into some larger type (i.e., any notion of first-class polymorphism).

One of the simplest example would be e.g.:

```
f : (∀α. α → α) → int × string
f id = (id 4, id "boo")
```

Inferring higher-rank polymorphism is known to be undecidable in general. Similar limitations apply to recursion: a recursive definition cannot have polymorphic *recursive* uses. For a contrived example:

```
g : ∀α. int × α → int
g (n,x) = if n = 0 then 0 else if odd n then g (n-1, 3) else g (n-1, "boo")
```

This is kind of unsurprising given the above, and the fact that a recursive definition like the above is just a shorthand for applying the higher-order Y combinator at a polymorphic type, which would again require (impredicative) first-class polymorphism.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, System F type inference has been proven undecidable by J. B. Wells in [Typability and type checking in System F are equivalent and undecidable](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~jbw/papers/#Wells%3aAPAL-1999-v98).

H-M type system allows type quantifiers only on the top level of type expressions. More precisely, H-M distinguishes *types*, which can't contain quantifiers, and *type schemas*:

> type := type variable | type → type
>
> type schema := type | ∀α . type schema

And polymorphic expressions are typed using type schemata.

So any type that has type quantifiers inside a type expression (in particular inside the left part of →) can't be expressed in the HM type system.

One example could be typing of [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals). Their type in System F is `∀α.(α→α)→(α→α)`, and while this alone can be expressed in HM, we can't express types where a Church numeral is used as an argument. For example if define exponentiation on Church numerals

```
(λmn.nm) : (∀α.(α→α)→(α→α)) → (∀α.(α→α)→(α→α)) → (∀α.(α→α)→(α→α))
```

this type can't be expressed in the HM type system, because of the type quantifiers in the arguments.